# Is there a way to use circe-optics' JsonPath with strings, just as in jq CLI tool?

Tags: json, scala, lenses, circe, monocle-scala

What I'd like to do, is having field descriptor defined as `field1.field2[1].field3`, access value `two` of json:

```
{
  "field1": {
    "field2": [
      {
        "field3": "one"
      },
      {
        "field3": "two"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I know I can do that using `applyDynamic` and `root.field1.field2.index(1).field3`, but is there a way to create such a lens using a string?

Comment: applyDynamic accept String

Comment: Thank you @WeiChingLin for the pointer! - this is the correct answer.  In fact, `selectDynamic` works a little nicer, eg.

`root.selectDynamic("some.path").string.getOption(jsonObj)`
(where you can switch out 'string' to be one of the other types in [io.circe.optics.JsonPath](https://github.com/circe/circe-optics/blob/master/optics/src/main/scala/io/circe/optics/JsonPath.scala), such as boolean or int, etc.   

The import you need is `io.circe.optics.JsonPath._`

Comment: `root.selectDynamic("some.path")` does not work. I do not see anything in JsonPath that would allow you to do such a query.

Instead `"some.path".split(".").foldLeft(root)((p,f) => p.selectDynamic(f)).string.getOption(jsonObject)` works.

Or without optics: `"some.path".split(".").foldLeft[ACursor](json.hcursor)((p,f) => p.downField(f)).as[String].toOption`

Comment: `"some.path".split(".")` should be `"some.path".split("\\.")` or `"some.path".split('.')`